# Will there be a Win64 API?

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

If I'm correct, Win32 is adapting or has been adapted to cope with 64 bit windows, for example, GetWindowLongPtr on 64 bit as opposed to GetWindowLong on 32 bit. Will there be a Win64 Api, and if so, is there any indication on when the transition will happen?

I'm not very knowledgeable on this subject so I apologize if I have anything obvious wrong. Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This transition happened around the turn of the century. 64 bit versions of Windows using the 64 bit version of Win32 have been in use for a long time now.

However, the 64 bit version of Win32 is still known as Win32 since it is essentially an identical interface with the only major difference being different sized pointers.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an official source/citation for "the 64 bit version of Win32 is still known as Win32".  It seems like Microsoft actually wants us to refer to the 64 bit version of the Windows API as "Win64", according to this reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx

Comment: @David why not say win64?

Answer (score 3):

The new Windows API, just announced, is called WinRT.  For more information, I recommend watching the keynotes from [BUILD](http://www.buildwindows.com/).

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question. 64 bit Windows API has been extant for years and years.

Comment: @David: It addresses the future API for Windows, and shows how Microsoft is thinking about the Windows API in general.  The OP already showed how the current API is adapted for Windows to support 64bit platforms.  This shows what the newest, future API for Windows, in general, is heading...

Comment: WinRT is certainly interesting, but it feels like a different question from the one that was asked. Perhaps I misread but it felt to me like Ell feels that the transition to 64 bit Windows API is only partially complete.

Answer (score 3):

The win32 stuff ("Win32 API") in x64 is really 64-bit code through-and-through (* see comments).

The actual 32-bit code (in a 64-bit windows) runs under the [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) subsystem which encompasses both the file-system and registry. While this may seem "sloppy" it actually makes a good bit of sense because a program can be compiled for both x32 and x64 without needing to change names (so long as proper version-neutral code has been used) -- that is, the core interface and "how windows works" is a fairly stable target.

Happy coding.

Comment: This isn't quite true. A lot of Win32 code runs as 32 bit code under the WoW64 emulator. For example consider the code in kernel32, user32, comctl32 etc. This is all 32 bit code under WoW64 and 64 but under x64. The kernel of the OS (ntoskrnl) is pure 64 bit. But that's not Win32.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows API has suffered terribly from the habit of assuming a known value of `sizeof(void *)` and sticking it in a field of some integral type believed to be the same size.  Even in the [Windows `MSG` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `wParam` is so named because it was originally a WORD, or unsigned 16 bit value, and `lParam` a LONG, or signed 32 bit value.  Perhaps this is another symptom of [C Programmers' Disease](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/C-Programmers-Disease.html).