# My DLL is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have built a DLL with Visual Studio 2008 which a third party software is supposed to load and use.

On my old server this works perfectly well, but on the new server the third party complains that it cannot load my DLL. In order to test this behaviour I run my DLL with rundll32.exe using the entry point which also the third party software uses.

On the old server the rundll32.exe call terminates without complaining, however on the new server I get a windows popup window stating: 
"There was a problem starting C:\MyDll.dll.
C:\MyDll.dll is not a valid Win32 application."

The DLL is compiled for 64 bit, and both Servers have Windows 7 64 bit SP1 installed.

Do you have any suggestions what could be causing my problems? Is there a way to get more information on what is causing the loading of my DLL to fail?

**EDIT:**

- My dll is 64 bit
- Both rundll32.exe are 64 bit
- The deployment proccess should be correct: I copied the dll in the correct folder in which the third party application expects it to be, also the rundll32.exe would complain about not finding the dll if it wasn't there.

Comment: And the dll is 32 bit ?  *Which* `rundll32` version are you using the 32-bit or the 64-bit one? *Where* and how did you deploy your dll? Did you copy a 32-bit DLL in `System32` instead of the 32-bit folder`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` ? A Windows Installer package (MSI) would deploy the dll to the correct folder. If you copy the file directly you should ensure it's placed in the correct folder

Comment: Is that third-party software 32-bit or 64-bit? A 32-bit application *can't* load 64-bit dlls

Comment: Have you tried compiling and deploying a 32-bit build of the DLL? If that works, it's likely that the new server's rundll32.exe is actually 32-bit rather than 64-bit.

Comment: @Rhymoid 64-bit Windows versions have *both* 32 and 64 bit versions of rundll32. In fact, as long as you don't put a 32-bit file on a 64-bit folder or vice versa, Windows takes care of calling the correct version.

Comment: If you read the words in the message, it tells you exactly what the problem is: You're trying to load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process, and that 64-bit DLL is **not a valid Win32 application** (because it's 64-bit). You either need to build a Win32 version for your *third party*, or your *third party* needs to build a Win64 version of their application that can load your 32-bit DLL. Words in error messages almost always convey useful information, but those words are only useful if you actually read them.

Comment: @KenWhite AFAIK, Win32 is the name of the abstract API (as opposed to WinRT or .NET) and does not indicate whether you're using 32-bit or 64-bit code. [There is no Win64](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7476913/824425).

Comment: @Rhymoid: Search here for that exact error message, and you'll see that every existing question is the result of a *bitness* mismatch. It should be pretty clear (by  reading the words I wrote) that by *Win64* I was referring to *a version compiled for 64-bit Windows*, but then again this entire post is due to not actually reading words.  :-)

Comment: Try: "Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules. For each module found, it lists all the functions that are exported by that module, and which of those functions are actually being called by other modules. Another view displays the minimum set of required files, along with detailed information about each file including a full path to the file, base address, version numbers, machine type, debug information, and more." http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @KenWhite I don't know, with Microsoft's screwed terminology, calling that "Win64" is quite confusing.